# PHP how to encode chars for UNICODE 2.5 RFC 4627

Tags: php, unicode, encode

my question is how to encode chars for UNICODE 2.5 RFC 4627 ?

i have followed example:

string `śmieć śmieć.txt` and with `urlencode` is encoded to :`%9Cmie%E6+%9Cmie%E6`>

and i want to use the representation for Unicode characters described in section 2.5 of RFC 4627

where for example 'ą śżź' -> '\u0105 \u015b\u017c\u017a'.

Answer (score 0):

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) already escapes non-ASCII characters to `\u`-escapes by default, unless you give it the option `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`.

```
echo json_encode("śmieć śmieć.txt");

"\u015bmie\u0107 \u015bmie\u0107.txt"
```

Note [RFC 7158](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7158) is the more up-to-date standard for JSON.